# Geoserver WMS-T backend problems

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wms, sql-server, time

I've been trying to set up a few timed WMS layers in GeoServer. They're simple enough, of the form

```
ID(PRIMARY KEY) REGION DATE VALUE
```

so for every region and date you have some value, e.g. the precipitation in that day.

When I set up the layer without time dimensions, I get a working layer where I can see all my regions (although each of them is present multiple times, once for every corresponding date).

Then, I enable the time dimension, with `attribute = DATE` and `presentation = LIST`. When I call `GetCapabilities`, it really contains something like

```
<Dimension name="time" default="current" units="ISO8601">
  2003-12-31T00:00:00.000Z,2004-12-31T00:00:00.000Z,2005-12-31T00:00:00.000Z
</Dimension>
```

However, when I request `GetMap`, results vary.

- with MS SQLServer backend, I get blank image if the type of `DATE` column is `date`, but I get the correct map image if it is `datetime`
- with PostGis backend, I always get blank image, whether I use `date` or `timestamp`

( one day granularity is enough for my list, so to represent `2003-12-31` I'm ok with using any timestamp within that day )

Note that GeoServer considers all of these datatypes compatible with the time dimension and allows the user to set them as the time attribute.

Has anyone encountered such problems? Am I misunderstanding something about the WMS-T?

**EDIT:** I've recently found out that `timestamptz` is the type that works with PostGis. Still, why...?